# Registering two different istances of the same service type with a name in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I've developed a wrapper around IBMMQ classes that performs some operations I need based on which queue it connects (but in this case it's just explanatory, can be whatever type of class).
I was wondering if I can register an instance of `IMyWrapper` with a name/tag (call it A) and resolve it somehow, then another instance of `IMyWrappaer` (call it B).

The problem is not registering it, but resolving the specified instance I need via constructor, how can I ask to have an instance of A, or of B?

The first thing that came to my mind was to create an `IMyWrapperA` that inherits from `IMyWrapper`, and the other one that is of `IMyWrapperB`

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions that come to mind, but which one you need depends on your scenario. Best is to read about both approaches:

- [Context-based](https://simpleinjector.org/advanced#context-based-injection)
- [Resolving instances by key](https://simpleinjector.org/howto#resolve-instances-by-key)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Steven, as usual, in both case I need to perform a different RegisterInitializer<IMQService> based on the instance I need to create, since I have to read different parameters from the config... is this possibile? Thanks

Comment: @advapi: Please add the details to your initial question and ping me once you did. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm currently following a production issue, please excuse me if I have not answered to your post, I'll update it tomorrow asap I've finished this mess..... sorry